# Angular artifact in Azure contains ~43k files

Tags: node.js, angular, azure

So I have this this small Angular project of mine and every time I try to deploy it to Azure, it uploads ~43k files as an artifact. I'm not any good at deployment to Azure, so this may as well be a really stupid question, but still.

So, here is my GitHub Actions workflow file

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - minesweeper

on:
  release:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --prod
        working-directory: .

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'minesweeper'
          publish-profile: $
          package: ./dist/minesweeper_
```

[image: A]

So, here I have a path, that matches my project's name: minesweeper_ and app name is from azure

[image: Here is the GH log]

What am I doing wrong here

https://github.com/yan14171/Minesweeper - here is the repo itselff

Answer (score 2):

> There are over 10,000 files in this artifact, consider creating an archive before upload to improve the upload performance.

As per [documentation](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/master/packages/artifact/docs/additional-information.md#considerations):

- During upload, each file is uploaded concurrently in 4MB chunks using a separate HTTPS connection per file. Chunked uploads are used so that in the event of a failure, the upload can be retried. If there is an error, a retry will be attempted after a certain period of time.
- Alternatively, you can try zip and unzip steps as mentioned by [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69402502/15969115).

You can refer to [React Deployment on App Service Linux](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/02/07/React-Deployment-on-App-Service-Linux/),  and [Deploying Node.js to Azure App Service with GitHub Actions](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/twil-deploying-node-js-to-azure-app-service-with-github-actions-e5244073966e)